# Result type does not implement method in scope named `unwrap`

Tags: rust

For some reason, the Rust compiler is complaining that `Result` doesn't implement `unwrap`, even though the Error type I provided does implement Debug. The code that's error-ing is provided below.

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Debug};
use std::error::Error;

trait MyError: Error + Display + Debug {}
type MyResult<T> = Result<T, MyError>;

trait Foo: Clone {}

trait MyTrait {
    fn my_function<T: Foo>(&self) -> MyResult<T>;

    fn unwrap_function<T: Foo>(&self) -> T {
        self.my_function().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you define your type

```
type MyResult<T> = Result<T, MyError>;
```

You actually define your type to be an [unsized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html) as `MyError` is not a concrete type, but a trait. But, the implementation of `Result<T, E>` states

```
impl<T, E> Result<T, E> where E: Debug {
    /* ... */
}
```

Which implicitly requires `E` to be a sized type. Thus in your case, as it is not, the implementation is invalid and unavailable (actually, most if not all of the implementation of `Result<T, E>` requires `T` and `E` to be sized, so an unsized `Result` is not very useful).

The simplest fix in your case is to put your error in a `Box`, like this:

```
type MyResult<T> = Result<T, Box<MyError>>;
```